# VBA project works fine on machine with outlook 2013, but not on a machine running outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, vba, microsoft-outlook-2013

Both machines are running 64-bit versions of Windows 7. The project has been painfully pieced together, I am not a programmer.

The function of the project is to automatically search emails for attachments upon a reminder set to fire every night and only download attachments to specified pathway that have the string defined by the two `pos` lines of code. Basically it just checks if the file name contains the desired name/phrase. The files I am working with change slightly with every email and over the years, but always contains the one statement. If the mail was `unRead`, it marks it as `read` when it is done with all the attachments in each email.

The only other difference is the machine with Outlook 2010 does have some other code running on it. I placed this code on the machine with Outlook 2013 to see if it was conflicting, but it ran perfectly still.

The following code works beautifully on the machine with Outlook 2013, but not at all on the machine with Outlook 2010. The project compiles just fine, and `runs` but does not download any files nor mark any emails as unread.

Here is the code in `This Outlook Session`

```
Private WithEvents MyReminders As Outlook.Reminders

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set MyReminders = GetOutlookApp.Reminders
End Sub

Function GetOutlookApp() As Outlook.Application
    ' returns reference to native Application object
    Set GetOutlookApp = Outlook.Application
End Function

Private Sub MyReminders_ReminderFire(ByVal ReminderObject As Reminder)
    'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    If ReminderObject.Caption = "Daily Report" Then
        ReminderObject.Dismiss
        Daily_Report
    End If

    If ReminderObject.Caption = "Shutdown Outlook" Then
        ReminderObject.Dismiss
        Application.Quit
    End If

 ProgramExit:
     Exit Sub
 ErrorHandler:
      MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
      Resume ProgramExit
 End Sub
```

And Here is the code I have on `Module1`, this is only because of the pre-existing code on the other machine. I know it doesn't have to be in the module.
Here it is:

```
Sub Daily_Report()
    ' This Outlook macro checks a the Outlook Inbox for messages
    ' with attached files (of any type) and saves them to disk.
    ' NOTE: make sure the specified save folder exists before
    ' running the macro.
    On Error GoTo GetAttachment_err

    ' Declare variables
    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileNameXLS As String
    Dim FileNamePDF As String
    Dim posXLS As Integer
    Dim posPDF As Integer

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    ' Check each message for attachments
    For Each Item In Inbox.Items
         ' Save any attachments found
         If Item.UnRead = True Then
             For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
                 posXLS = InStr(Atmt.FileName, "FINAL EXCEL")
                 posPDF = InStr(Atmt.FileName, "Final PDF")

                 If posXLS <> 0 And (Right(Atmt.FileName, 4) = ".xls") Or posXLS <> 0 And (Right(Atmt.FileName, 5) = ".xlsx") Then
                     FileNameXLS = "C:\Users\ba\Downloads\Babcok Lab Reports\Babcock Excel\" & Atmt.FileName
                     Atmt.SaveAsFile FileNameXLS
                 End If

                 If posPDF <> 0 And (Right(Atmt.FileName, 4) = ".pdf") Then
                     FileNamePDF = "C:\Users\ba\Downloads\Babcok Lab Reports\Babcock PDF\" & Atmt.FileName
                     Atmt.SaveAsFile FileNamePDF
                 End If
             Next Atmt
             Item.UnRead = False
         End If
     Next Item

' Clear memory
GetAttachment_exit:
    Set Atmt = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    Exit Sub
' Handle errors
GetAttachment_err:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
        & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
        & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: GetAttachments" _
        & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
        & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
        , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If you run VBA on Outlook 2010 without the conflicting code, does it run fine? Then its a matter of working out the conflict... I use this code myself for saving attachments: `Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "c:\temp"
     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
End Sub
`

Comment: When I run the VBA on outlook 2010, there arent any errors or problems at all. Nothing happens. Even when I remove all of the other code, nothing happens. It runs like a dream on outlook 2014. The reminder fires and it does its thing. Thanks for the reply. I will give your code a try tonight.

Comment: Just figured out that my code is not seeing any items in the inbox, even though I have two unread items in the inbox. I have no idea why......continuing the search. Also, I tried your code and kept getting run-time error '91'. I tried to make it work, but do not know VBA well enough to create objects from scratch. maybe once i am done with this project I will know it though.

Comment: StackExchange also has codereview and stackoverflow which have more competent individuals for reviewing VBA scripts, or to help you rewrite partially working code. Just make sure you explain what you've tried already and explain what results you want. I flagged your question for StackOverflow... maybe one of the moderators will move it there.

Comment: Thanks, I posted it there as well. Haven't seen much help yet.

Comment: Please cross post...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean Ramhound

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally figured it out. My code was looking at the Outlook Data File "Inbox" when all the mail was going into the gmail account Inbox that outlook was setup with. Once I redirected the mail into the "Data File Inbox" via an inbox "rule" the code worked beautifully. Alternatively, I probably could have redirected my code to look in the gmail inbox, but didn't know how to easily do this being an amateur in programming. Any suggestions for the alternate will be appreciated.